# Oracle12c: External tables unable to open file

Tags: database, windows, oracle, oracle12c, external-tables

I've checked questions about same problems but advices seen theme didn't help me.

1. I've created external table using user **tpch1**.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE region_ext (r_regionkey  NUMBER,
   r_name VARCHAR2(25),
   r_comment VARCHAR2(152))
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
   TYPE oracle_loader
   DEFAULT DIRECTORY tpch1_dir
   ACCESS PARAMETERS (
   RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
   PREPROCESSOR zcat_dir:'zcat'
   NOBADFILE NODISCARDFILE NOLOGFILE
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
   MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
   )     
   LOCATION ('region.tbl.gz'));
   ```
2. User tpch1 created directories: zcat and tpch1_dir and has read and write permissions to them.
3. Trying to select on this table I get

   ```
   select count(*) region_count from region_ext
   *
   ERROR at line 1:
   ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
   ORA-29400: data cartridge error
   KUP-04001: error opening file E:\mgr\datadir\region.tbl.gz
   ```
4. I'm working on Windows 7, Oracle 12c. It's for use during the studies so I can change everything.
5. I've also changed properties of these directories. Now Everybody can use it fully and the owner is also Everybody.

Plese help me finding the solution :)

Comment: You say that `zcat` is a directory but `zcat` appears to be the name of an executable.  I assume that `zcat_dir` is a directory.  What Windows user is running the Oracle service?  That Windows user would need to have access to the Windows drive in question.  Is the E:\ drive local or a network share?  If that is a network share, it's likely not visible to the Windows user that runs the Oracle service.  Using UNC paths might help (though, again, the Windows user would need appropriate access).

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, you're right. I thought about zcat_dir.
This is a local drive. 

How can I check which user runs oracle? But I assuce that every user has access to this drive

Comment: If you look at Services in Control Panel and find the Oracle service, you can see what user it is running as.  Most likely, it isn't running as a domain user (assuming your Windows machine is on a domain).  Does "assuce" mean "assume"?  Or "assure"?  Or something else?  Are you implying that the drive is a network share rather than a local drive?  Are you certain that "every user" includes non-human local service accounts?  Does that non-human actually mount an E:\ drive or is that only done for you when you log in?

Comment: I haven't done this on Windows, so just a random thought; does the preprocessor command have to include the suffix, i.e. `zcat_dir:'zcat.exe'`?

Comment: @AlexPoole aa... I didn't have this command there. So now I've created sth like
`@echo off
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e %1`

@JustinCave there should be assume. Sorry. This is a local drive. The user running oracle is shown as .\mgr where mgr is the main Oracle user created during my db creation. What is weird for me, I wanted to grant privilages to it (using sqlplus) but it shows that such user does not exist.

Comment: @Anna - from SQL\*Plus you can grant privileges to a database user (as listed in `dba_users`), which are usually independent os OS users. Justin was asking about the *operating system* user that is running the Oracle processes and services. This doesn't look like a Oracle directory object privilege problem since it's showing the full file path in the error. Do you get the same thing running your .bat file instead?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, I understand the difference between these users, but I still do not know why it does not work. I can run the script and it works.